# Online Windows server virtual drive images for use with VMWare Server 1.0

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vmware-server

I have a remote Server running the VMWare hypervisor. I want to create a virtual machine running Windows Server. However I can't upload mine since my internet connection is slow (would take me days to do the upload).

Microsoft has public hard drive images with Windows Server trial on them, but they work for Virtual PC.

I am looking for such files that can be used with VMWare Server. That case I can download these files directly to the server which enjoys a fast connection.

Answer (score 0):

VMware's official repository of images is here:
http://www.vmware.com/appliances/

They appear to have images of several versions of Windows Server.

You can also install VMware's converter software on the server and the download the Virtual PC images and convert them:
http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to download Windows Server iso from official web site: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016 ?
I am running evaluation of Windows Server 2012 Standard for 4 month of ESXi 6.2 and it just works.